# How do I create a generic method to return an array of the enum values instead of its constants?

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have an enum with descriptions as String. This is the enum.

```
public enum tabs
{
    A("Actual data"),
    B("Bad data"),
    C("Can data"),
    D("Direct data");

    private String description;
    tabs(String desc)
    {
        this.description = desc;
    }


    public String getDescription()
    {
        return this.description;
    }
}
```

Now, if I need the data for A, I'd just do

```
tabs.A.description
```

I am in the process of creating a generic method to return the values.

I have managed to utilize the below generic method to accept an enum type as the argument. 
It returns an array of the enum constants. 
But I actually want it to return an array of the values.. ie {"Actual data", "Bad data", "Can data", "Direct data"}.

```
public static String[] getActualTabs(Class<? extends Enum<?>> e) 
{
    return Arrays.stream(e.getEnumConstants()).map(Enum::name).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

What options do I have to achieve this?

Comment: Suggestion to improvement: In Java, the classes are capitalized, e.g., String, Integer, and Class. Enum is just a constant class so `tabs` should be `Tabs`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass a mapper `Function` to map enum constants into `String`s:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> String[] getActualTabs(Class<T> e, Function<? super T, String> mapper) 
{
    return Arrays.stream(e.getEnumConstants()).map(mapper).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getActualTabs(tabs.class,tabs::getDescription)));
```

Output:

```
[Actual data, Bad data, Can data, Direct data]
```

Comment: This definitely works. Thanks. I do have a related question though. Let's say I have to pass in different enums. What becomes of the mapper argument then? tabs.class is one enum. Let's say I also have servers.class as another enum. And I have to pass in a generic for the mapper argument. How do I tackle such a situation? How can tabs:getDescription be also converted into generic? I mean I want to get rid of the hardcoded tabs::getDescription and make it so such that I can pass in any enum... sort of like: <enum.name>::getDescription

Comment: @SteroidKing666 Using a mapper `Function` argument gives you more flexibility. For `tabs` you want to obtain the values of `getDescription()`. For some other enum, you might want to obtain the values of a different property (say `getColor()`). If your `server` enum also has `getDescription()`, you can pass `server::getDescription`. If you only want to support `getDescription()` method, you can use something like Mureinik's answer (i.e. require that the enum implement some interface).

Comment: @SteroidKing666 if you are concerned about having to specify the enum name in the method reference, you can use a lambda expression instead : replace `tabs::getDescription` with `e -> e.getDescription()`. This will work for any enum that has a `getDescription` method that returns a `String`.

Comment: Okay so getActualTabs(enumName,e->getDescription()) should work. What if enumName is of type Class<? extends Enum<?>> class1 ? That is, I am accepting class1 as a generic enum into a method. And then passing that generic enum class1 into getActualTabs. Because then getActualTabs(class1,e->getDescription()) wouldn't work.

Comment: @SteroidKing666 in that case I don't think it will work, since the compiler doesn't know that `class1` has a `getDescription()` method, unless you add a generic type bound as in Mureinik's answer.

Comment: I was trying out his answer but I get Incorrect number of arguments for type Class<T>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <? extends Enum<?>, Script1.HasDescription>. My enums and the HasDescription interface are all within the same class.

Comment: Just curious: Shouldn't there be a `<T extends Enum<T>>` somewhere? Otherwise, `e.getEnumConstants()` doesn't work.

Comment: @glglgl that's an interesting question. I tested the code posted in the answer, and it works. I'll try to explain that.

Comment: @Eran Just found out it on my own: `.getEnumConstants()` is a method for all `Class<>`es. If it is not an enum type, it [just returns `null`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants()), so your function throws a NPE. So while the `<T extends Enum<T>>` isn't absolutely necessary to make it compile, it is better to have it, because it prevents NPEs on misuse.

Comment: @glglgl it's weird that it passes compilation. It must be doing some unchecked conversion somewhere. I managed to pass an non enum class to that method. The compiler didn't complain, and I got NullPointerException when running it. Will edit the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @glglgl Ah, so the compiler behaved just fine. I fixed the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @Eran any idea why I am getting "Incorrect number of arguments for type Class<T>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <? extends Enum<?>, HasDescription>" for Mureinik's answer?

Comment: @SteroidKing666 I just checked the JLS. It appears wildcards (?) can only have a single type bound (unlike type variables that can have multiple bounds). Can't you change your methods to have a type parameter T (with the relevant type bounds) and accept a `Class<T>` instead of `Class<? extends Enum<?>>`?

Comment: Sorry. I am very new to generics. I have been struggling to figure this out itself. How could I implement parameter type T in your code for example?

Comment: @SteroidKing666 It would be as in my answer - `<T extends Enum<T>>`. If you want to use Mureinik's suggested interface, change it to `<T extends Enum<T> & HasDescription>`.

Comment: That works. And what happens to the "Class<? extends Enum<?>> class1" which I am passing into the root method which carries the getActualTabs method? It wouldn't be Class<T> class1 for the root method right? This is the root method: private <T> void verifyTabData(Class<? extends Enum<?>> class1)

Comment: @SteroidKing666 It should be `Class<T>`, otherwise you can't define the required type bounds.

Comment: Using Class<T> as a parameter in the root method gives me a compile time error for me.

Comment: @SteroidKing666 does that root method declare the type parameter T (with the required type bounds)?

Comment: This is how it looks: private <T> void secureServer(boolean flag, Class<T> class1, String devType){ getActualTabs(class1,e->e.getDescription());} and then followed by your code for getActualTabs. So I am passing in an enum through Class<T> class1.

Comment: @SteroidKing666 Again, try `<T extends Enum<T> & HasDescription>` instead of `<T>` in `secureServer` method.

Comment: Private void secureServer(boolean flag, <T extends Enum<T> & HasDescription> class1, String devType) : This also does not compile. Also I must say that I am calling it like so: secureServer(true,piper.class,"certificate")

Comment: @SteroidKing666 `private <T extends Enum<T> & HasDescription> void secureServer(boolean flag, Class<T> class1, String devType)`?

Answer (score 4):

I'd first pull `getDescription` out to an interface and make sure all your project's enums implement it:

```
public interface HasDescription {
    String getDescription();
}
```

And then, use it in your generic method:

```
public static String[] getActualTabs(Class<? extends Enum<?> & HasDescription> e) {
    return Arrays.stream(e.getEnumConstants())
                 .map(HasDescription::getDescription)
                 .toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Comment: I get the idea. But somehow I am getting the following error: Incorrect number of arguments for type Class<T>; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <? extends Enum<?>, Script1.HasDescription>. My enums and the HasDescription interface are all within the same class.

Comment: I think you'll have to re-write this with a generic type variable, since wildcards can only have a single type bound (i.e. `Class<? extends Enum<?> & HasDescription> e` doesn't pass compilation)

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are quite beautiful.

But there is another variant which might be more superior because it is even more widely usable:

```
public static <T> String[] getActualTabs(T[] values, Function<? super T, String> mapper) {
    return Arrays.stream(values)
                 .map(mapper)
                 .toArray(String[]::new);
}

public static <T extends HasDescription> String[] getActualTabs(T[] values) {
    return Arrays.stream(values)
                 .map(HasDescription::getDescription)
                 .toArray(String[]::new);
    // or just: return getActualTabs(values, HasDescription::getDescription);
}
```

This implementation has the benefit that we don't have to mess around with reflection.

Instead, you would call them this way:

```
String[] tabs1 = getActualTabs(Tabs.values())
String[] tabs2 = getActualTabs(Tabs.values(), Tabs::getDescription)
```

Note that it might be useful to rename the functions, e. g. `getStringifiedValues()` or `toDescriptions()`.

Disclaimer: untested, but should work, IMHO.

Comment: How would I implement this if I have another generic method called private <T> void verifyTabData(Class<? extends Enum<?>> class1) which holds the getActualTabs method? I am passing in different sets of enums into this root method.

Comment: @SteroidKing666 If all what makes the difference is the list of values, you can work with `{EnumType}.values()` everywhere. If you are restricted to this signature, you can call `.values()` resp. `.getEnumConstants()` in this function. Or you would resort to the original alternative in order not to disturb the original concept completely.